# Any hits to localhost redirect me to IIS welcome page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, localhost

I'm trying to debug my application but any URLs which contain `localhost` (I've tried IIS Express, Local IIS, a simple Node server, and a Python development server) are redirected to the IIS welcome screen.

Examples:

> localhost:xxxx/MyController
>
> localhost:xxxx/SomeFolder/SomeFile.html
>
> localhost/MyApp/MyController
>
> localhost/MyApp/SomeFolder/SomeFile.html

The URL changes from the full url to my external IP address (i.e., URL changes from `localhost:xxxx/MyController` to simply `XX.XX.XX.XX`)

I just tried launching with a brand new ASP.NET "Empty Web Site," just loading the `index.html` file, and same situation.

There are no entries in my `hosts` file and it appears that this is only happening in Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried disabling local iis?

Comment: I haven't, but I will... that said, that shouldn't be the issue; it never was in the past.

Comment: I'm just saying if it helps, have you tried resetting Chrome?

Comment: @Hosein, how do you mean?  I've tried clearing the cache and history -- is there a more robust way (other than reinstall...which I haven't tried, but perhaps should)

Comment: @Tom, You can delete the "C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" folder and it will be like you've reinstalled Google Chrome.

Comment: Your question is short on details, maybe you want to add your IIS configurations (app pools and sites and their bindings and any redirects or rewrites) and your application's configuration (web.config) and any handlers in your HTTP application class (global.asax.cs) and your routes config.

Comment: Can you run `NET STOP IISADMIN /Y` from `cmd`, and then, run the solution from Visual Studio, is the solution configured to use IIS Express ?

Comment: Can you use 127.0.0.1 instead localhost? Maybe it will not redirect to the external ip?

Answer (score 0):

This works in php, so it may help you with ASP:

1. Run Notepad as administrator
2. Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file
3. add the following line to hosts file

   **127.0.0.1:123 yourserver.com**
4. Save
5. Run command prompt using CMD in run or type it in start menu
6. Type this command and hit enter

   **ipconfig /flushdns**
7. Close
8. go to yourserver.com

I hope this help you. Again, this works fine with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DNS is resolving the *localhost* hostname. If you're using your ISP's DNS, this may happen. You could change the DNS to [Google's Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/). By pointing the DNS server to IP's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. See the link for details on how to configure your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for.